# How to identify top 30% salary in python dataframe

Tags: python

I have dataframe as follows:

| Employee | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| Tony | 50 |
| Alan | 45 |
| Lee | 60 |
| David | 35 |
| Steve | 65 |
| Paul | 48 |
| Micky | 62 |
| George | 80 |
| Nigel | 64 |
| John | 42 |

The  question is to identify:

1. Top 30% gets a value “high”
2. The next 40% gets “average”
3. the Rest as "Low"
   -and put it in a new column as the corresponding value

it would be easy to identify top N of them but top 30% is something I am unable to understand how to go about the %. Can anyone help me with python code for this??

Comment: If top N is easy for you, then think about this: If there are a hundred people, the top 30% are the 30 people with the best salary

Comment: Here's an easy solution for beginners: You can sort your dataframe by "salary" and then assign the value "high"/"average"/"low" based on that sort. For example `df.sort_values("Salary").iloc[0:int(0.30 * len(df))]['value']='high'`. Do the same for "low" with a reverse sort, and then use df.fillna to fill the rest. BTW, you need a definition of 30% - is is 30% of money or 30% of top earning employees... - this example is for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the boundaries.

```
# Bound of top 30%
bound1 = (df["salary"].max()-df["salary"].min())*(70/100) + df["salary"].min()

# Bound of bottom 30%
bound2 = (df["salary"].max()-df["salary"].min())*(30/100) + df["salary"].min()
```

edit, oh, you want a further col denoting the high/avg/low, gimme a sec

```
df["band"] = None
df["band"] = df["band"].mask(df["salary"] > bound1,"High")
df["band"] = df["band"].mask((df["salary"] > bound2) & (df["salary"] < bound1),"Avg")
df["band"] = df["band"].mask(df["salary"] < bound2,"Low")
```

I'm sure someone could do it slicker than that, but I'm about to get in crap from boss, so gotta run!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what a percentage actually is, it only shows the proportion of something. It depends on the amount of people in your list.

Therefore, the top 30% can actually be translated into a number of people.

Assume your data  has N employees. Taking the top 30% salaries is the same as taking the 30xN/100 people that have the biggest wage.

If you order your data, then the only thing you actually have to do is setting "high" for these 30xN/100 people, "average" for the 40x100/N next, and "low" for the rest